# how to solve this question without using extra space?

Tags: c++

Given a m x n matrix, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0. Do it in-place.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void setZeroes(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        for(int i=0 ; i<matrix.size() ; ++i){
           for(int j=0 ; matrix[i].size() ; ++j){
               if(matrix[i][j]==0){
                   
                   int col=0, row=0;
                   while(col<matrix.size()){
                       matrix[col][j]=0;
                       col++;
                   }
                   while(row<matrix[i].size()){
                       matrix[i][row]=0;
                       row++;
                   }
                   break;
               }
           }
        }
    }
};
```

**While traversing where ever I get a zero I make that row and column zero,**
**I don't know why I getting a run time error**

Comment: Does it matter if you change `matrix[a][b]` to `matrix.at(a).at(b)`?

Comment: What's the runtime error you're getting?

Comment: your algorithm won't work, once you find a zero, you'll zero out the whole matrix, because you don't discriminate between original zeros and zeros you put in the matrix yourself -- that's the main point of this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to solve it in one pass, which is a good thing, but sometimes it would make the solution complicated.

This solution is pretty easy to understand, would pass through, and it does not require extra space, yet we would be doing it with multiple passes, which is totally fine because the time complexity would remain the same.

```
#include <vector>


class Solution {
public:
    void setZeroes(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix) {
        bool is_zero_col = false;
        bool is_zero_row = false;
        int row_length = matrix.size();
        int col_length = matrix[0].size();

        for (int row = 0; row < row_length; row++) {
            if (matrix[row][0] == 0) {
                is_zero_col = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < col_length; col++) {
            if (matrix[0][col] == 0) {
                is_zero_row = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 1; row < row_length; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < col_length; col++)
                if (matrix[row][col] == 0) {
                    matrix[row][0] = 0;
                    matrix[0][col] = 0;
                }
        }

        for (int row = 1; row < row_length; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < col_length; col++)
                if (matrix[row][0] == 0 || matrix[0][col] == 0) {
                    matrix[row][col] = 0;
                }
        }

        if (is_zero_col) {
            for (int row = 0; row < row_length; row++) {
                matrix[row][0] = 0;
            }
        }

        if (is_zero_row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < col_length; col++) {
                matrix[0][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/set-matrix-zeroes/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if your matrix does not have elements equal to max int value.
At first find all zeros and set max int value for corresponding rows and columns.
Then set zero for all max values.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void setZeroes(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix) {
        constexpr auto max_value = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        for (auto& col : matrix) {
            const auto zeroElem = std::find(col.begin(), col.end(), 0);
            if (zeroElem != col.end()) {
                std::fill(col.begin(), col.end(), max_value);
                const auto index = std::distance(col.begin(), zeroElem);
                for (auto& sCol : matrix)
                    if (index < sCol.size()) {
                        sCol[index] = max_value;
                    }
            }
        }

        for (auto& col : matrix)
            for (auto& elem : col)
                if (max_value == elem)
                    elem = 0;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix;
    Matrix.insert(Matrix.end(), { 1,1,1,1,1,1 });
    Matrix.insert(Matrix.end(), { 1,1,1,1,0,1 });
    Matrix.insert(Matrix.end(), { 1,1,1,1,1,1 });
    Matrix.insert(Matrix.end(), { 1,1,0,1,1,1 });
    Matrix.insert(Matrix.end(), { 1,1,1,1,1,1 });

    Solution s;
    s.setZeroes(Matrix);
    for (auto& sCol : Matrix) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (auto& Elem : sCol) {
            std::cout << Elem << ' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 1
```